# How to get individual frames from a VLC MediaPlayer livestream on Android WITHOUT displaying the stream?

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I am currently working on a project that requires me to stream video from an IP camera to an Android device via WiFi using RTSP and then do some image processing. I want to do this *without* displaying the video stream if possible. Currently, I am trying to do this using VLC for Android. My code is structured as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    // Various options added.

    mLibVLC = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext(), options);
    mMediaPlayer =  new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);
    videoLayout = findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // This view is marked as INVISIBLE.
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mMediaPlayer.attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false);

    Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse("<RTSP LINK>"));
    // Set VLC media presets.

    mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
    media.release();
    mMediaPlayer.play(); // Play the stream!
    
    // Set callback to get each frame from MediaPlayer?
}
```

When `videoLayout` is marked as "visible", this works perfectly. I am also able to get Bitmaps from the view by performing a screen capture. When I mark the `video layout` as "invisible", far as I can tell I am still receiving frames (at least according to VLC's debug output) but I'm not sure how I can access them. Is there a way for me to directly render the MediaPlayer stream to a Bitmap? Or is there some other method I could use to get each new frame without rendering the view? Thanks for your help!

Comment: look into the video callbacks if using libvlc 3.x, but this is CPU intensive. To get GPU acceleration you need the opengl callbacks available in libvlc 4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out after a lot of trial and error. The solution that worked best for me was to use `FFMPEGFrameGrabber` from JavaCV. I'm now able to read frame by frame from an RTSP stream.